# Getting error connecting to Kafka Kerberos

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kerberos, gssapi

getting this error :-

SASL authentication error: SASL handshake failed (step): SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: An invalid name was supplied (Success) (after 25ms in state AUTH_REQ)

kinit command is working fine with the keytab file, need to know what might be the issue?

Looked over internet, tried changing file permission of krb5.conf file, nothing changed.